# Any genuine difference between file formats for fonts

Tags: css, svg, fonts, typography

I have a custom font in the following formats (with filesize):

> font.eot (66kb)
>
> font.svg (204kb)
>
> font.afm (79kb)
>
> font.otf (107kb)
>
> font.woff (42kb)
>
> font.pfb (130kb)
>
> font.ttf (66kb)

So the **exact same font** has completely different file size depending on the format. .woff is smallest in size.

According to the `@font-face` page on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp), EOT works on IE6+ while other formats work on IE9+ — besides that, I can't find any information on differences between these formats.

My question is, does it make any difference in terms of quality or compatibility choosing which format?

Comment: Not sure about quality, but in term of compatibility, `.EOT` is used for IE<=8 and `.SVG` is used for iOS Safari 3.2-4.1. Here is a good [reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-cross-browser-web-fonts-part-1/).

Comment: @HashemQolami Interesting, so SVG is the safest bet for everything besides IE?

Comment: Well, not actually. SVG font is unimplemented in Firefox. See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119490

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely yes.  Here is a great article about the exact question you are asking.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/

There is another font type that you did not list and is the most recommended format in terms of file size (smallest) and browser compatibility: WOFF (Web Open Font Format).

If you are targeting IE 8 and below you will need to use something in conjunction with WOFF.  Here is an example targeting legacy browsers:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Graublauweb;
    src: url('Graublauweb.eot'); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
    src: url('Graublauweb.eot?') format('eot'),  /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('Graublauweb.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('Graublauweb.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('Graublauweb.svg#svgGraublauweb') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

And while not completely "there yet" in terms of browser adoption rates, the future will be WOFF 2.0 as the compression rates will be near 30% - 50% compared to WOFF.

Here is another resource that describes the different font formats:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

**TrueType Fonts (TTF)**

TrueType is a font standard developed in the late 1980s, by Apple and Microsoft. TrueType is the most common font format for both the Mac OS and Microsoft Windows operating systems.

**OpenType Fonts (OTF)**

OpenType is a format for scalable computer fonts. It was built on TrueType, and is a registered trademark of Microsoft. OpenType fonts are used commonly today on the major computer platforms.

**The Web Open Font Format (WOFF)**

WOFF is a font format for use in web pages. It was developed in 2009, and is now a W3C Recommendation. WOFF is essentially OpenType or TrueType with compression and additional metadata. The goal is to support font distribution from a server to a client over a network with bandwidth constraints.

**The Web Open Font Format (WOFF 2.0)**

TrueType/OpenType font that provides better compression than WOFF 1.0.

**SVG Fonts/Shapes**

SVG fonts allow SVG to be used as glyphs when displaying text. The SVG 1.1 specification define a font module that allows the creation of fonts within an SVG document. You can also apply CSS to SVG documents, and the @font-face rule can be applied to text in SVG documents.

**Embedded OpenType Fonts (EOT)**

EOT fonts are a compact form of OpenType fonts designed by Microsoft for use as embedded fonts on web pages.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to add it. And it is true, it is the smallest, check updated question.

Comment: I am just curious, how exactly does that piece of code work? All I see is a list of the different formats, so doesn't they just override themselves and the final one become the "active" one? Which is how CSS works in general..

Comment: @HenrikPetterson `src` descriptor accepts a list of URLs/formats of fonts separated by comma `,`. UAs (web browsers) must choose the first accessible/acceptable URL/format from the list. The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-fonts-3/#src-desc) states: `When a font is needed the user agent iterates over the set of references listed, using the first one it can successfully activate. Fonts containing invalid data or local font faces that are not found are ignored and the user agent loads the next font in the list.`

Comment: Note also that SVG fonts cannot support the complex scripting requirements of Devanagari based languages such as Hindi.